# Can a non-VLAN-aware switch pass 802.1q tagged packets?

Tags: switch, vlan, 802.1

Let's say I have a incoming connection which is fixed 1Gb/s with tagged packets.  And lets say that I need to connect that connection to a device which is a 10/100 device, which deals with the tagged packets.

Can I use a dumb (ie: non-VLAN-aware) 1Gb switch to connect that 1Gb connection and the 10/100 Mb device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the tagged packets do not exceed the supported MTU of the unmanaged switch, the tags should be propagated just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Not all switches will pass this information.  In the past, I have personally seen cheap netgear switches reset that portion of the frame back to 00's.
This was a couple of years ago, but be aware that it's possible that your packets will be changed.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the dumb switch is a Linksys EG008W.  Linksys doesn't say anything about MTU, but [this evaluation](http://www.epinions.com/review/Linksys_EG008W_Instant_Gigabit_8_Port_Workgroup_Switch_745883555994/content_466893704836) talks about testing the switch with jumbo frames and it works.  So I would suspect this will work.

Comment: You generally want to add this information either as an edit to the original question, or as a comment to the original question, rather than as an answer to the original question.

Comment: Thank you.  I also enjoyed the irony of someone with 600 reputation explaining to someone with 6K reputation how to use the site.  If the question is "will this work generally?" then an answer is "in this specific case, probably yes."